# Trying to add a char to my if statement

Tags: groovy

This is Java/Groovy (we're learning syntax first). I've been stuck on it for 2 days.

This is my code:

```groovy
char am = "a";
char pm = "p";

def to24hour(int hour) {
    if (hour >= 1 && hour <= 12) {
        int newHour = hour + 12;
        return newHour;
    } else if (hour >= 13 && hour <= 24) {
        int newHour = hour
        return newHour;
    } else if (hour == 0){
        int newHour = hour
        return "invalid number used!";        
    } else {
        return "invalid number used!";
    }
}


to24hour(3);
```

This is the question:

> Write a function called `to24Hour` that takes two parameters: an hour value and a letter that should be either A or P. The function converts a time specified as AM or PM to hours on the 24 hour clock. So, for example, calling the function with values 5 and P should return 17 whereas 5 and A should return 5. What are the possible problems with such a function (if invalid values are used)? How could you deal with these problems?

Comment: Well, it's not Java.

Comment: Not java and your not passing 2 parameters

Comment: @markspace OP stated that this is java/groovy?  How is this not java/groovy?

Comment: you've enclosed char in double qoutes

Comment: @markspace yes but I am asking to know how it would be done. def means define, which is the same as function  .

Comment: @user2846003 Are you asking how to translate this Groovy code into Java?  Your question is very unclear if that is the case.

Comment: @markspace What I am trying to do is, add "char" to the IF Statement, so it can determine whether it's AM or PM. This would then decide which line to return but I am struggling with this.

Comment: @user2846003 Well, I don't speak Groovy, I only speak Java, so I don't really know how to do that either.  I'm really confused why you tagged this question Java in the first place.

Comment: @markspace ok, as you see the question above. How would you answer that in Java? I can then convert it over to groovy which is near enough identical. We're learning groovy for 4 weeks, then we do Java. I'm just struggling with this question and its holding me back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
char am = "a";
char pm = "p";

int to24hour(int hour, char clock) {
    if (hour >= 1 && hour <= 11) {
        if(clock == "p") return hour + 12
        else return hour
    } else if(hour == 12) {
        if(clock == "p") hour
        else return 0
    } else {
        throw Exception("invalid number used!")
    }
}

[1..12, (1..11).toList() + [0]]
    .transpose()
    .each { assert to24hour(it[0], am) == it[1] }

[1..12, (13..23).toList() + [12]]
    .transpose()
    .each { assert to24hour(it[0], pm) == it[1] }
```

Comment: Darn it. Fixed to account for midnight. I recall doing something like this before. I think I used a category so that I could do: `5.am` and `5.pm`.

Comment: Thanks! I used this as a reference and managed to build my answer around it.